# Java enum getter

Tags: java, enums

I would appreciate any help here.

executing the following code, Buyer2 ID always override buyers1 ID. Means I always get ID=2. I am not sure what is wrong with the following code. I think it is my enum and the get method which always retains the last value.

```
Buyer bOne = new Buyer("buyer1", 1); 
Buyer bTwo = new Buyer("buyer2", 2);
```

rest of the code:

```
public enum Fruits {
    Banana("banana", "B"),
    Apple("apple","A"),
    Orange("orange","O");

    private String type, ID;

    private Fruits(String type, String ID){
        this.type = type;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID){
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private Fruits banana, apple, orange;

    private int ID;

    public buyer(String name, int ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
        banana = Fruits.Orange;
        apple = Fruits.Apple;
        orange = Fruits.Orange;

        banana.setID("B"+ID);
        apple.setID("A"+ID);
        Orange.setID="O"+ID;
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: You have a `Player` class. Did you mean `Buyer`?

Comment: `enum` doesn't work like that.  With `enum`, there is only one Apple, only one Banana and only one Orange. Can you describe what you want your code to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Fruits` enum is mutable, which is probably not what you want. The `setID()` method on `Fruits` is probably a design error. As the different fruits (Banana, Apple, ...) are a single instance, shared through your all program, they need to reflect some globabl state, not some state specific to the buyer.

Try to remove this setter and see if you can refactor your code ...

Comment: I guess I need to Look into enums and study them carefully. It sounds like the enums are mostly suitable for constants

Comment: There is no problem having mutable state in your enum, but there is only one instance of an enum, so its state is global.

Answer (score 0):

Fruits.java

```
package test;

public enum Fruits {

    Banana("banana", "B"), Apple("apple", "A"), Orange("orange", "O");

    private String type, ID;

    private Fruits(String type, String ID) {
        this.type = type;
        this.ID = ID;

    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
}
```

Buyer.java

```
   package test;
    public class Buyer {
    private String name;
    private Fruits banana, apple, orange;

    private int ID;


    public Buyer(String name, int ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
        banana = Fruits.Orange;
        apple = Fruits.Apple;
        orange = Fruits.Orange;

        banana.setID("B"+ID);
        apple.setID("A"+ID);
        orange.setID("O"+ID);

    }
    public static void main (String  []args){

            Buyer bOne = new Buyer("buyer1", 1); 
    System.out.println("id = " + bOne.ID + " name =" + bOne.name);
    Buyer bTwo = new Buyer("buyer2", 2);
    System.out.println("id = " + bTwo.ID  + " name =" + bTwo.name);
    }
    }
```

Result on consol :

id = 1 name =buyer1

id = 2 name =buyer2

Comment: Orange.setID="O"+ID;   to   orange.setID("O"+ID),   générate setter & getter and add a main class to test

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your last line:)

```
Orange.setID="O"+ID; -> orange.setID="O"+ID;
```

Comment: This is irrelevant; `Orange` and `orange` both point to the same (static final) enum constant.

Answer (score 0):

each instance of the enumeration is guaranteed to be constructed exactly once and because of this the last value retains.

Comment: Thanks,  
I guess I need to Look into enums and study them carefully. It sounds like the enums are mostly suitable for constants